# Import Image as Plane Without Cropping

Tags: add-on, image

I'm using the Import Image as Plane add-on to import RGBA PNG-24's. My issue is that the add-on automatically crops the planes, which changes the images' location relative to the world origin.

As you can see from the attached images, once imported into Blender, the image is cropped, which changes the location. There doesn't seem to be any option to change this behavior in the plug-in, is there a work-around?

I am using Cycles, Blender 2.83

[image: Image in Photoshop]

[image: Image in Blender]

Comment: A work around could be to add pixels in the corner of the image that are basically invisible

Answer (score 0):

can you supply an image?  I made one with Gimp, that is png with alpha and had no problem.  Not sure it is png24 or not.
[image: test Image]

Yes, I'm using the 'Import as images' addon.
That one worked too.
[image: testimage]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ERBckyV are you using the Import Images as Planes add-on? For me it works fine if I manually import the PNG and add it to a material.